# I want to accept an input size of around 10 ^ 5. But the problem is my python code only takes 4096

Tags: python-3.x, input, large-data

Example lets say of python:-

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = int(input())

    for _ in range(q):
        string = input()
        # assume string's length is more than 5000
        print(len(string))
        # this displays 4096 no matter how much more than 4096 the input size is.
```

What I want is to accept large input size for operations.
But it only accepts strings of limited length.
Can I get alternative solutions to accept input size around 10 ^ 5
Where the length of the respective programming language shows accurate length

1. In a program if we generate string length of 10 ^ 5 and then using the length function it shows the correct length.
2. Same way if I have a file size of 10 ^ 5 input size, the code shows correct input length.
3. Then why terminal doesn't show correct input length when that much input is supplied to terminal.

Comment: My guess is that you are using a terminal that only suppors 4K inputs, or that your terminal supports more but you have configured it to only support 4K.

Comment: Is there a way to increase the limit?